# Select distinct row with an empty column but not when empty column is not part of a duplicate row

Tags: hive, hiveql

Using Hive, I have duplicate rows and i want to drop duplicate rows (selecting distinct row with non empty column) when a particular column is empty. But I want to keep the rows when the column is empty but not in duplicate row.

e.g. Input is

```
id | name | fathername | address
 1 | bob  | john       | street1
 1 | bob  | john       | 
 2 | amir | khan       |
 3 | roby | johanson   | street3
```

Output

```
id | name | fathername | address
 1 | bob  | john       | street1
 2 | amir | khan       |
 3 | roby | johanson   | street3
```

We dropped row for id 1 when address was empty because it was a duplicated row. Although address for id 2 is missing, we still want to keep the row because its not a duplicated row. I need it for hive. There are many columns in actual problem and solution need to work with selecting * rather than particular columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` with `MAX`:

```
select id, name, fathername, max(address)
from data
group by id, name, fathername
```

Or if you want to use `select *`:

```
select *
from data
where address is not null
union
select *
from data 
where address is null and id not in (
  select id 
  from data
  where address is not null
)
```

Comment: Will it work with select * as well because * will also contain address.

Comment: No, you will need to use max in the first one. Added version with select *

Answer (score 0):

You can prioritize the non-null address row in an `order by` using `row_number`.

```
select *
from (select t.*
      ,row_number() over(partition by id order by case when address is not null then 1 else 2 end) as rnum
      from tbl t
     ) t
where rnum = 1
```

Note: If there is more than one non-null row, you might have to specify one or more columns to break the ties.