# SQL select distinct rows with occasionally empty column but keep 1 copy if empty column is part of distinct row

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have duplicate rows and i want to drop it with the following logic when there is empty column:

- Drop it if there is a duplicate row with more data
- Keep 1 copy of it if there are multiple duplicates with empty column

The only resource I found is this [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53309374/select-distinct-row-with-an-empty-column-but-not-when-empty-column-is-not-part-o) which doesn't exactly fit my need.

Input is

| id | first | last | address | phone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | bob | john | street1 | 1234 |
| 2 | bob | john |  | 1234 |
| 3 | bob | john | street1 |  |
| 4 | amir | khan |  |  |
| 5 | amir | khan |  |  |
| 6 | roby | johanson | street4 |  |
| 7 | roby | johanson | street5 |  |

Output

| id | first | last | address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | bob | john | street1 |
| 4 | amir | khan |  |
| 6 | roby | johanson | street4 |
| 7 | roby | johanson | street5 |

We drop row 2 and 3 because row 1 have more complete data.
Row 5 is drop because of duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

This would be simple in SQLServer using Row_Number() function. Gets complicated in Access which does not support that function. Following produces desired output with sample data.

```
SELECT ID, first, last, address FROM table1 WHERE ID IN(
    SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM table1 AS Dupe WHERE Dupe.first = table1.first 
    AND Dupe.last = table1.last AND Dupe.address = table1.address 
    ORDER BY Dupe.Address DESC, Dupe.Phone DESC, Dupe.ID DESC) 
AND NOT Address IS NULL
UNION SELECT ID, first, last, address FROM table1 WHERE ID IN (
    SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM table1 AS Dupe WHERE Dupe.first = table1.first 
    AND Dupe.last = table1.last AND Nz(Dupe.address,"xxx") = Nz(table1.address,"xxx") 
    AND NOT last & first IN (SELECT last & first FROM table1 WHERE NOT address IS NULL) 
                         ORDER BY Dupe.address DESC, Dupe.phone DESC, Dupe.ID);
```